# Inquiry about Running the Source Code - CSI-Prediction Repository

Tags: pytorch, stem

I am interested in the 'CSI-Prediction' repository by sharanmourya available on GitHub at https://github.com/sharanmourya/CSI-Prediction. This repository contains PyTorch code for 'Spectral Temporal Graph Neural Network for massive MIMO CSI Prediction.' I would like to run the code and reproduce the results mentioned in the associated research paper.

I have gone through the repository and the README file, but I would appreciate more detailed instructions on how to properly execute the code. If anyone has successfully run this code or has experience with similar projects, I would greatly appreciate your guidance. Any detailed instructions, clarifications, or tips on running this code would be invaluable.

Thank you in advance for your help!

In step 2 of the setup process, it is mentioned to use STNet for compression. Could you please provide more information on how to acquire and utilize STNet for the compression process? Are there any specific instructions or guidelines to follow?